# How do I declare an array of functions?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, switch-statement

This is part of a CMD Prompt Calc:

1) it display options with 0 - 9

2) user enters number that matches the function they want

Rather then having 10:`case i: //do stuff here`

can I have an array containing the functions;

```
functionArrayName = [(float cosx(float _cx);), (float sinx(float _sx);) ... etc ]
```

then have a for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
if(i = userInput){
   //call the function in functionArrayName[i];
}}
```

Comment: you could have `std::array<std::function<double(double)>, N>`

Comment: What @Borgleader said. Otherwise, you might want to search for and learn about *function pointers*.

Comment: How would I seperate the functions?
`array = {"function1", "function2 etc... }` ?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg that may be a good idea, I will do that thank you. My experience with function pointers is .... yea no comment.

Answer (score 3):

Ugly but, hey, it's what you asked for...

```
float (*arr[])(float) = { cosf, sinf,...};
...
float result = arr[i]();
```

Comment: note that this is an array of function pointers, not an array of functions (which is not possible)

Answer (score 1):

You appear to come from a more "flexible" language, BTW.

Anyway, your code has several errors:

First, what matters most:

```
functionArrayName = [(float cosx(float _cx);), (float sinx(float _sx);) ... etc ]
```

Shall actually be:

```
#include <array>
#include <functional>

// ...

std::array<std::function<float(float)>> functionArrayName;
```

Note that this `std::array` will only be able to hold function(-like) objects that return a `float` and take a single `float` argument.

Secondly...

```
if(user = input) {
```

Shall (in most cases) be:

```
if(user == input) {
```

Although (in some cases only), that expression was valid, it usually indicates a misunderstanding of comparison operators.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The last brace is not invalid; it is part of the `for` loop

Comment: Heh, sorry, didn't noticed that. I usually get into those errors when reading non-indented code. Edited.

Comment: With `std::array` you also have to decide on the number of elements you want to store.

Answer (score 1):

The following is similar in spirit to what you asked for, but using modern C++

```
#include <functional>

extern float cosx(float);
extern float sinx(float);
// ... add more

std::function<float(float)> functionArray[] = {cosx, sinx, /*... add more */};

int main() {
  int userInput = 0;
  float x = 3.14159/2;

  float y = functionArray[userInput](x);
}
```